# R Two Variables in Loop

Tags: r, data.table

I need to loop a function over a named list, with `list[i]` as one argument, and `names(list)[i]` as the other.

Here is some fake code:

```
#generate DF

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

df <- data.table(employee, salary, startdate)
df$'tags' <- NA

#Create named list

test <- list(
  'JMan' = 'Doe',
  'PMan' = 'Peter',
  'JMan' = 'Hope'

)

#Create function to populate df$tags with output

func <- function(pattern, name) {
  df[, tags := fcase(
    employee %like% regex(pattern), name,
    rep(TRUE, nrow(df)), as.character(df$tags)
  )
  ]
}
#test function

df <- func(as.character(test[1]), names(test)[1])
```

This all works fine:

```
         employee salary  startdate tags
1:   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01 JMan
2: Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25 <NA>
3: Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14 <NA>
```

However, when I try to iterate over it:

```
for (i in test) {
  df <- func(as.character(test[i]), names(test)[i])
  
}
```

Nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried used apply() and apply(), but no luck.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: FYI `func(as.character(test[1]), names(test)[1])` does not work on my end, even just by itself

Comment: maybe try `for (i in seq_along(test))`

Comment: If you remove `df <- func(as.character(test[i]), names(test)[i])` and try `print(as.character(test[i]))` you'll see that it returns `NULL` values at every step, which might help explain why nothing happens. @chinsoon12's solution provides a working solution, but it just writes an identical data frame over the original one. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the function to and use `for` loop to replace.

```
library(data.table)

func <- function(df, pattern, name) {
  df[grepl(pattern, employee), tags := name]
}

for (i in seq_along(test)) {
  df <- func(df, test[[i]], names(test)[i])
}

df
#     employee salary  startdate tags
#1:   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01 JMan
#2: Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25 PMan
#3: Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14 JMan
```

**data**

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

df <- data.table(employee, salary, startdate)
df$tags <- NA_character_
```

Comment: Note, you don't have to capture df, thats part of the beauty with data.table, it works by reference.

Comment: Hi Ronak, solution worked great. Though I am a little confused as to how `df[grepl(pattern, employee), tags := name]` modifies the column. If this a shorthand if `ifelse`?

Comment: `grepl(pattern, employee)` filters the rows that have `pattern` in them and for those rows we assign `tags := name`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an additional answer, compacting it some and doing away with the for loop, just to offer additional ideas. (note can you guarantee there will be only one match per employee?)

```r
df <- data.table(employee, salary, startdate)

func <- function(employee) {
    i <- sapply( unlist(test), grepl, x=employee[1] )
    if(!any(i))
        return(NA)
    names(test)[i]
}

df[, tags := func(employee) , by=1:nrow(df) ]
```